# What is the difference between these two ways of writing a structure?

Tags: c, structure

```
struct one
{
    int member;
};

struct two
{
    int member;
} structure;
```

If I want to call the above structures in the `main()` function then in the first case do I need  to name the `struct one` to any random name of my choice and then and then call its member like this:

```
int main() {
    struct one random_name;

    random_name.member = 1;
}
```

and in the second case I have already named the `structure` so it's just that I can directly call the member with the name `structure` like this:

```
int main() {
    structure.member = 1;
}
```

Is the version below valid or do I have to put `typedef` in front of the `struct`?

```
struct {
    int member;
} structure;
```

Comment: The second case `struct two { int member; } structure;` (where I've added the missing type for the member) defines a variable called `structure` of type `struct two`.  Did you have in mind to precede the definition with `typedef`?  You don't usually 'call' structure members — unless perhaps they are pointers to functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `int` as the type of the structure members throughout, then:

```
struct one
{
    int member;
};
```

This is a perfectly fine definition of the type `struct one`.  It defines no variables of type `struct one`; it is simply a type that can be used later in the translation unit.

```
struct two
{
    int member;
} structure;
```

This is a perfectly fine definition of the type `struct two` and is also the definition of a variable `structure` of type `struct two`.

> If I want to call the above structures in the `main()` function then in the first case do I need to name the `struct one` to any random name of my choice and then and then call its member like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct one random_name;

    random_name.member = 1;
}
```

If you want to use a variable of type `struct one`, you will have to define it, and the way you've done so is fine.  You don't 'call' members of structures.  You use them.

> and in the second case I have already named the `structure` so it's just that I can directly call the member with the name structure like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    structure.member = 1;
}
```

This is also valid because you defined the variable `structure` at the same time as you defined the type `struct two`.

> Is the below version valid or do I have to put `typedef` in front of the struct:

```
struct
{
    int member;
} structure;
```

This is also legitimate code.  It defines an anonymous structure type and defines a single variable of that type.  It is the only variable of that type that can exist, but occasionally it is useful to use this.

Note that if the last `structure` was followed by:

```
struct
{
    int member;
} form;
```

the types of the variables `form` and `structure` are different; you cannot legitimately assign one to the other, for example, or pass either of them to another function, etc.

More typically, you either give the structure type a tag (`struct three`) or use a `typedef` (`typedef struct { int member; } four;`) or both (`typedef struct five { int member; } five;`, where it is legitimate to use the same name for the tag and the type name as I showed, though there is also an extensive tradition of using different names for the type and the tag).

---

> So with `typedef struct { int member; } structure;`, in `main()` creating one or more variables of type `structure` is possible, like this?
>
> ```
> structure first_var;
> structure second_var;
> ```

This is entirely legitimate.  You could instead write:

```
structure first_var, second_var;
```

though many people prefer one variable per declaration.

> Whereas if we don't use `typedef` and just do `struct { int member; }structure;` then I have just got one variable with name `structure` and can use that only in `main()`, such as `structure.member = 1;` and can't create more.

More or less.  You can write:

```
struct { int member; } var1, var2, … varN;
```

and now you have multiple variables all of the same type.  However, although you can write:

```
struct { int member; } var1;
struct { int member; } var2;
```

the two variables `var1` and `var2` are not officially of the same type.  There are complicated bits of wording in the standard in section 6.2.7 Compatible types and composite types which might let you off the hook, but GCC 4.9.1 set fussy says:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c tagless.c
tagless.c: In function ‘main’:
tagless.c:13:10: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct <anonymous>’ from type ‘struct <anonymous>’
     var1 = var2;
          ^
$
```

#### tagless.c

```
struct
{
    int member;
} var1;
struct
{
    int member;
} var2;
int main(void)
{
    var1.member = 1;
    var2.member = 2;
    var1 = var2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for correcting all my mistakes and +1 for such a great explanation :)

Comment: can i create more variables in main of type struct two keeping in mind i already declared the struct two above and created `structure` variable their ?

Comment: Yes; after you've defined the type with a name, you can use the name as often as necessary. If you define a tagless struct without using typedef too, you can only define variables in the one declaration.

Comment: two more doubts ::::: So with **`typedef struct{int member;}structure;`** ::::: in main() creating one or more variables of type structure is possible? Like this -> `structure first_var` & `structure second_var`:::::::::::Whereas if we don't use `typedef` and just do **`struct{int member;}structure;`** then i just got one `variable` with name `structure` and can use that only in main `structure.member=1;` and can't create more

Answer (score 0):

```
two more doubts:::::::
```

Whereas if we don't use typedef and just do struct{int member;}structure; 
then i just   got one variable with name structure and can use that only in 
main structure.member=1; **and can't create more –**

Ans : You can always create more than just one variable once you have declared the   structure, so its not that if you dont use typedef you can have only one variable for your   structure. For eg:

```
struct structure
    {
      int number;
    };

    int main()
    {
      structure var1, var2, var3; //...any number of variables can be declared here.  
      var1.number = 30;  
      var2.number = 45;  
      var3.number = 90;  
      printf("\nvar1 = %d, var2 = %d, var3 = %d\n", var1.number, var2.number,   var3.number);  

      return 0;  
    }  

For a better understanding of typedef,  
Consider this example :   

1.

    struct structure  
    {  
       int number;
    };

typedef struct structure structure;  

2.

    typedef struct structure
    {
      int number;
    }structure;  

---------------------
```

Both of the above declarations are equivalent.

typedef is used to define a new name for a variable or a keyword.
Suppose in case if your structure declaration is something like this :

```
    struct this_is_my_structure  
    {
      int number;  
    };
```

then every time you declare an instance of this structure you will have to use this   long name in front of your instance, like:

```
int main()  
{
  struct this_is_my_structure var1; // you dont want to write such long types for    variables  
  var1.number = 23;  
  return 0;  
};  

You will find typedef helpful here :  

typedef struct this_is_my_structure structure;
```

Now every time you want to declare an instance of type "this_is_my_structure" all you   have to do is the following :

```
    int main()  
    {
     structure var1;  
     var1.number = 23;  
     return 0;
    }
```